# How to highlight specific text using Selenium/ selenide and javacript executer

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenide

I'm using selenium/ Selenide java test automation and I need to highlight the word '**Environment**'. This need to be done using mouse event either double click on that or mouse move.
Once this is done I should able to see another window.
Currently, I tried multiple ways to do that and didn't succeed. Looking for help on that.

**This is the sample element I'm trying**
`<h2>Local Environment Setup</h2>`

**This is how elements locate**
[image]

**These are the ways I tried**

```
 //Try 1 double click using selenide
 $(content).doubleClick();

//Try 2 double click using js
((JavascriptExecutor) getWebDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].dblclick;",content);

//Try 3 using x and y (This returns error saying MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException)
 String jsDoubleClick =
            "var target = arguments[0];                                 " +
                    "var offsetX = arguments[1];                                " +
                    "var offsetY = arguments[2];                                " +
                    "var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();                 " +
                    "var cx = rect.left + (offsetX || (rect.width / 2));        " +
                    "var cy = rect.top + (offsetY || (rect.height / 2));        " +
                    "                                                           " +
                    "emit('mousedown', {clientX: cx, clientY: cy, buttons: 1}); " +
                    "emit('mouseup',   {clientX: cx, clientY: cy});             " +
                    "emit('mousedown', {clientX: cx, clientY: cy, buttons: 1}); " +
                    "emit('mouseup',   {clientX: cx, clientY: cy});             " +
                    "emit('click',     {clientX: cx, clientY: cy, detail: 2});  " +
                    "                                                           " +
                    "function emit(name, init) {                                " +
                    "target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(name, init));        " +
                    "}   ";
                    ((JavascriptExecutor)getWebDriver()).executeScript(jsDoubleClick, content, content.getLocation().x, content.getLocation().y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the mouse to the element by coordinates from its center and Doubleclick with `Actions`:

```
//locate the element somehow
WebElement h2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2")); 

// try to move to the _Environment_ world center, you have to find the x value
// 0 - is element center (for Selenium 4 W3C)
int x = -100; // -100 worked for this site
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(h2, x, 0).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

This worked for me (just found some similar site):
[image]

Comment: how we get the x path value ? and this is change depends on the screen size, So is there way to get correct x value for any screen ?

Comment: x is some indent from the element center, where you expect the correct word placed. You can try to take the full element width `element.getSize().getWidth();`, then you can devide the full width on 5 or 10, and choose the sign for x (+ or -). Anyway the solution won't work for everything, you have to tweack it for some caces.